# PowerShell Save Content Into File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write into a file in PowerShell. I'm willing to write the result of **StrAddSpace** function with **$StrTemp2** and **80** arguments into **$OutputFilePath** which is a path to a file  that I've already created.

```
for($z=0 ; $z -lt ($FinalString.Length) ; $z++)
{        
    $StrTemp1 += $FinalString[$z]
    $y += 1

    if($i -eq 2 -and $y -eq 72)                   
    {
        $h += 1
        $StrTemp2 = $h + $StrTemp1
        Add-Content -path $OutputFilePath -value StrAddSpace $StrTemp 80
        $y = 0
        $StrTemp1= ""
        $i = 0
        $h += 7                    
    }
}
```

It throws me the following error :
**Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'**

What am I doing wrong or what is the right way to write it?

Comment: `StrAddSpace $StrTemp 80` -> `(StrAddSpace $StrTemp2 80)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Ansgar Wiechers commented, you need to wrap your argument in parenthesis or your `$StrTemp2` is trying to be seen as a positional argument to `Add-Content` (and it is `$null` so the interpreter doesn't know what you're trying to do).

Function calls can be used as arguments, but they *do* need to be wrapped in parenthesis.

As an aside, please post your full error object in questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should wrap `StrAndSpace $StrTemp 80` with parenthesis as you say want its output to be accept as an argument of Add-Content.